# WOE in a magrittr Pipe

Tags: r

How can I get the weight of evidence code below into a magrittr pipeline (`df %>%`)? Nothing I've tried seems to work.

**df:**

```
library(Information)
library(magrittr)


#df
a = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
b = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
c = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
d = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
e = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)

cols <- c("c","d")
```

**code for pipe**

```
Enc <- create_infotables(data=subset(df, select = -c(a)), y="e", parallel=FALSE)

for(i in names(df[,cols])) {
  df[,i] <- Enc$Tables[[i]][match(df[,i], Enc$Tables[[i]][,1]), 4]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `map2`.  Here, we are checking for corresponding elements of the two objects i.e. column with a column from the `list` of data.frame (`Enc$Tables`).  So, an option is `map2`

```
library(purrr)
df[cols] <- map2_dfc(df[cols], Enc$Tables[cols], ~  .y[match(.x, .y[,1]), 4])
```

---

To use it in a pipe

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(-a) %>%
    create_infotables(data = ., y = "e", parallel = FALSE) %>%       
    pluck("Tables") %>%
    magrittr::extract(cols) %>%
    map2_dfc(df[cols], ., ~ .y[match(.x, .y[,1]), 4])
```

Comment: Is there a way to put "Enc <- create_infotables(data=subset(df, select = -c(a)), y="e", parallel=FALSE)" into the magrittr Pipe as well? I have other steps that have to occur first in the pipeline for "Enc" to be accurate.

Comment: @gojomoso you can do `create_infotables(data=subset(df, select = -c(a)), y="e", parallel=FALSE) %>% map2_dfc(df[cols], ., ~ .y[match(.x, .y[,1]), 4])`

Comment: "Error in .y[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: @gojomoso sorry, missed the extraction step, `create_infotables(data=subset(df, select = -c(a)), y="e", parallel=FALSE) %>% pluck("Tables") %>% magrittr::extract(cols) %>% map2_dfc(df[cols], ., ~ .y[match(.x, .y[,1]), 4])`

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to use the magritte pipe you can also try this: define a function which takes the column name as input and use `mutate()` and `across()` to apply it to all column names in vector `cols`.

```
library(dplyr)

enc <- function(col_name) {
  Enc$Tables[[col_name]][match(df[,col_name], Enc$Tables[[col_name]][,1]), 4]
}

df %>% 
  mutate(across(cols, function(x) enc(cur_column())))
```

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `c`.
x object 'Enc' not found
i Input `c` is `(function (x) ...`.

Comment: Did you run your own code Enc <- create_infotables(data=subset(df, select = -c(a)), y="e", parallel=FALSE) ?

Comment: First off, `mutate_at()` is a superceded function. Second, part of the point of mutate is to avoid having to use the anonymous function.