# magrittr Pipe Function Dropping Columns

Tags: r

I have a great Weight of Evidence encoding function from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63836165/woe-in-a-magrittr-pipe) but when trying to implement in my df I have been unable to figure out how to include it in my pipe and prevent it from dropping all other columns. I also want to make sure it is not "skipping" over the previous steps in the pipeline.

**df:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(Information)
library(purrr)

#df
a = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
b = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
c = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
d = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
e = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

**code for pipe:**
*Problem code is the last four lines.*

```
cols <- c("b","c","d")

#Prop Tables
freq = prop.table(table(unlist(df[cols])))
make_rare = names(freq)[freq < 0.05]

#Rare label encoding
rare_label <- function(x){
  replace(x, x %in% make_rare, "Rare")
}

#Pipeline
df %<>%
  #Drop Columns
  subset(select = -c(a)) %<>%
  #Rare Label Encoding
  mutate(across(all_of(cols), rare_label)) %<>%
  #Missing Category Imputation
  mutate(across(all_of(cols), ~ ifelse(.=='aa' | is.na(.), 'Missing', .))) %<>%
  #Factor
  mutate(across(all_of(cols), factor)) %<>%
  #WOE Encoding
  #Issues with the code below
  create_infotables(data=subset(df, select = -c(a)), y="e", parallel=FALSE) %<>% 
    pluck("Tables") %<>% 
    magrittr::extract(cols) %<>% 
    map2_dfc(df[cols], ., ~ .y[match(.x, .y[,1]), 4])
```

**Output:**
*Drop column "a"*

```
b              c             d             e
(WOE encoded)  (WOE encoded) (WOE encoded) 1
(WOE encoded)  (WOE encoded) (WOE encoded) 0
etc...
```

Comment: Do you need the `%<>%` pipe? In general I think it should be avoided in favor of `df <- df %>% ... %>% ...`. tidyverse style guide even states that. Honestly, I would break that last part out of the pipeline.

Comment: No, I was just using it for verification. You'd break it out entirely and write to a df?

Comment: Yeah, I would. I had trouble balancing how long to make pipes at first, but now have started breaking them down into shorter elements. I would end the pipe after the last `mutate()`. It'll be easier at that point to then just overwrite the columns you want as I think your prior question asked. No need to wrap it all into a pipe! If using the pipe doesn't make it easier, don't!